# Associate meal with time of day - Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, date, time

I am working on an app and there are 3 different restaurants. Each restaurant offers different meals on different days. There are 4 types of meals,

Breakfast,
Lunch,
Dinner,
Latenight

Now lets call the restaurant 1,2,3

And lets say restaurant 1 servers breakfast and lunch weekdays, and breakfast lunch and dinner on the weekend.

Now if it is a weekday and only breakfast and lunch are being served and it is before 10:30am I want to show the breakfast menu, but if it is after 10:30am then I want to show the lunch menu.

However if it is a weekend then I want to show breakfast before 10:30, lunch in-between 10:30 and 2:30 and dinner after 2:30.

How could I do this without just a bunch of if statements checking each sinerio as this has to be done for multiple restaurants and they are not all this simple with the number of options.

So the main question is how can I associate these arrays of strings (the meals) with the correct value depending on how many meals, and what the meals are, without just doing a bunch of if statements.

Thanks for the help, I know it was a long question.

Comment: You'd use a bunch of if statements. You'd also annoy paying customers if they cannot look at the dinner menu when they make their plans for the day in the morning.

Comment: Is there is a server side to keep all these info or you have to store it locally?

Comment: you will be able to switch, its just what the default one shown is depending on the time. And the data of the menu is stored on a server @nilam

Comment: @gnasher729 there is no other way?

Comment: okay..then send the current date and time to server, and server will give only the valid menu list in the response. On Server side the data must be in table. So server side can fire a query to fetch the required result. Also you can ask the menu for the day and then on your side you can check the time and provide list accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should send this request to the server, and assuming the data is in a table do a query, and then you can check on the server side what time it is and what time is should be so you can get the right data.